# GROUP_CONCAT is showing all recored

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to group_concate image_id and small_pic_path path based on messageid.
 But group concate is showing all image_id and path to first messageid

How to resolve this

Without group_concate it is working properly

```
SELECT user_messages.messageid,user_messages.message,
user_messages.sentby,user_messages.visibility,

post_images.image_id,
post_images.small_pic_path

FROM user_messages
      INNER JOIN smsusers ON
        user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
 INNER JOIN profile_pic ON
 user_messages.SENTBY = profile_pic.userid
left outer JOIN post_images ON
user_messages.messageid=post_images.messageid
WHERE user_messages.userid='1';
```

Showing proper output [Demo is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ce4/1)

I want to group_concate image_id, small_pic_path of post images based on messageid of user_messages
Which in not working properly

```
    SELECT user_messages.messageid,user_messages.message,
user_messages.sentby,user_messages.visibility,

GROUP_CONCAT( post_images.image_id SEPARATOR ';')
as Image_id,
GROUP_CONCAT( post_images.small_pic_path SEPARATOR ';')
as Image_path

FROM user_messages
      INNER JOIN smsusers ON
        user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
 left outer JOIN post_images ON
user_messages.messageid=post_images.messageid
WHERE user_messages.userid='1';
```

[Demo is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ce4/3)

Comment: Did you forget to use a `group by` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking `GROUP BY` clause,

```
GROUP BY  user_messages.messageid,
          user_messages.message,
          user_messages.sentby,
          user_messages.visibility
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9ce4/9)